# Assembly --> invalid combination of opcode and operands

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I have a variable called char that is supposed to change his value to a keyboard key when I press that key. I visited [How to change the value of a variable in assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27032852/how-to-change-the-value-of-a-variable-in-assembly) and it said for I to use `mov char, key_value`. The problem is that I got `terminal.asm:126: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands` . Searching for the solution online I saw that is necessary to put brackets [ ]. I tried that and the same error occurred.

Here it is a part of my file:

```
printChar:

    mov edx, char;

    loop5_terminal:
    mov al, [edx];
    mov byte [edi], al;
    inc edi;
    inc edi;
    inc edx;
    inc ebx
    call cursor_terminal
    cmp byte[edx],0;
    jne loop5_terminal;

    jne l2_terminal
l2_terminal:

    cmp al , 0x03      ; Checks for key 2 input

    mov char, [two]
    je printChar
```

Thanks.

Comment: In most assembly dialects you do not need to finish a line with a semicolon. A leading semicolon merely indicates the start of a comment.

Comment: This is not a complete example. In particular, it doesn't include the definitions of `char` and `two`, which are necessary for us to help.

Comment: Which line is the error occuring on? Show your full code.

Comment: Nowhere in the linked question or answer do I see any suggestion to use `mov char, key_value`.  (Which is a good thing because that wouldn't be valid unless `char` was defined as a macro that expands to different text, like a register name or an addressing mode including square brackets.  Because `mov char, whatever` would be like `123 = foo` in C, trying to assign to a constant.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you get is most likely due to the line

```
mov char, [two]
```

which contains two memory operands, namely `char` and `two`. This is not possible, because the x86 architecture does not support two memory operands in one instruction.

You'd have to split that "instruction" into two separate (valid) instructions like

```
mov al, BYTE [two]
mov BYTE [char], al
```

if you'd use a BYTE sized instruction.

Comment: At least, if OP meant `mov [char], [two]`- `mov char, [two]` is invalid syntax because `char` is a constant memory address.

Comment: If `char` would be a constant, the instruction `mov char, [two]` would be impossible, because there is no sense in moving a value to a constant.

Comment: My guess is that `two` is a constant, but that's why I asked for more information before writing an answer.

Comment: Unless `char` is a `%define` macro for something like `[edx]` or `[symbol`], `char` isn't a memory operand; it's an immediate in NASM syntax.  (So you definitely can't ever `mov` *to* it, even with a register source).  The problem would be two memory operands if both had `[]`.

Comment: Because my answer obviously doesn't cover all aspects that need to be addressed in answering this question, I leave it here until tomorrow as basis for someone writing a complete (_reads better_) answer.